# AWS Cognito Token with Authorization Code Grant PKCE returns {"error":"invalid_grant"}

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

This request was working a couple of months ago but when we tried again and directly using curl. It now returns an invalid_grant. I been trying to search the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html), but only see the following words without any exact reasons why?

> invalid_grant

- Refresh token has been revoked.
- Authorization code has been consumed already or does not exist.

The client settings is as follows.

[image]

```
curl -X POST https://test-sso.auth.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-d "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=xxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F1c2d5a1xxxx.ngrok.io&code=SjkkDSSDs-b2A7nJPi3cmItyRZU4-b3GMjLls&code_verifier=sdXXXXXbUR2RmFIaTVQaVpTdndLOWoxOFU9Ig"
```

Has someone experienced this lately or has resolved this issue? I realized, even removing the PKCE. It's still returns invalid_grant.

Many thanks

Comment: did you check whether the `Authorization Code grant` is enabled on the client ?

Comment: yes, it's on. Allowed OAuth Flows  - (check) Authorization code grant (un-checked) Implicit grant (un-checked) Client credentials

Comment: you should have secret generated for this client for authorization grant to work. can you confirm that?

Comment: Under "General" -> App Clients. "App client secret" says "(no secret key)". Is that correct?

Comment: you need secret generated for authorization code grant if i remember correctly

Comment: I eventually resolved this issue. There was a missing step that I missed as part of PKCE

Comment: @LouieMiranda it would be nice if you could document that missing step for posterity

Comment: Just a heads up; a client secrets IS NOT necessary for auth code flow with PKCE as suggested by @ArunKamalanathan

Answer (score 4):

I don't use PKCE to grant tokens however I was having the same issue.
Then I found in AWS docs that there are 3 reasons to cause this error:

> 1. Refresh token has been revoked
> 2. Authorization code has been consumed already or does not exist.
> 3. App client doesn't have read access to all attributes in the requested scope. For example, your app requests the email scope and your app client can read the email attribute, but not email_verified.

Reference: [Token Endpoint > Examples of negative responses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html#:%7E:text=access%20to%20all%20attributes)

In my case the problem was that I needed to provide read access to all attributes in the User Pool Client > OpenID Connect scopes and User Pool Client > Custom scopes

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html) says that you can get `invalid_grant` when the authorization code has been consumed already or does not exist.

You might have sent an incorrect token request before, which then invalidated the `authorization_code`. Make sure to use a freshly generated `authorization_code`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a client secret when using PKCE, which is explicitly designed for UI clients that can't keep one.

Your request and the overall behaviour both look entirely correct:

- An Authorization Code can be used once only
- If you try to use it again you get an invalid_grant error

Are you getting errors in real UIs or only with a cURL command? If it helps you can run my [Sample UI](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/)  and trace the HTTP messages, then compare to your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this one was happening because this scope was not selected.